# jQuery For loop with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have various list of radio button selections.

```
<fieldset id="radio_array">
{% for list in radio_selections %}
    {% for option in radio_selection %}
        <input id="{{option}}" type="radio" name="{{list}}" value="{{option}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
</fieldset>
```

I would like to determine which of the radio buttons are selected using Javascript/Jquery and for loop.
Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: please ask one question at a time

Comment: `$('#radio_array :radio').on('change', function(){alert(this.id);});` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input:radio").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).attr('id')); //print id element
 console.log($(this).is(':checked')); //print True if checked and false if not
})
```

Answer (score 1):

personally I would do this wich jQuery.each()
try something like this:
(not tested)

```
$('#radio_array').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(k,v){
    console.log($(this).id);
})
```